# Cannot convert value of type 'NSNull' to expected argument type

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am getting below error during Objective-C to Swift code change. Thanks

```
var sortedHours = gymDetail.hours.sorted(by: { ($0.startTime < $1.startTime) })
let gymdays = GymHours.orderedDays()
for i in 0..<(gymdays.count) {
    var pad = false
    if i >= sortedHours.count {
        pad = true
    } else {
        let hours = sortedHours[i]
        print(GymHours.orderedDays()[i])
        if  (hours.day == GymHours.orderedDays()[i] as! String) {
            pad = true
        }
    }
    if pad {
        sortedHours.insert(nil, at: i)
    }
}
```

my error screen [image: error]

my Objective-C code:

```
[sortedHours insertObject:[NSNull null] atIndex:i];
```

Comment: Error is pretty self-explanatory. The array expects its contents to be of `GymHours` type, `NSNull()` is, obviously, of `NSNull` type. Why exactly do you want to insert `NSNull` into that array?

Comment: Sending nil will resolve it, like [sortedHours insertObject:nil atIndex:i];

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: why do you want to insert a value of some other type (or nil) into an array that expects values of `GymHours` type?

Comment: can you print this `print(GymHours.orderedDays()[i])`

Comment: then try with `sortedHours.insert("", at: i)`

Answer (score 0):

This array `sortedHours` not optional values

Try This code

```
 var sortedHours: [GymHours?] = gymDetail.hours.sorted(by: { ($0.startTime < $1.startTime) })
            let gymdays = GymHours.orderedDays()
            for i in 0..<(gymdays.count) {
                var pad = false
                if i >= sortedHours.count {
                    pad = true
                } else {
                    let hours = sortedHours[i]
                    print(GymHours.orderedDays()[i])
                    if  (hours.day == GymHours.orderedDays()[i] as! String) {
                        pad = true
                    }
                }
                if pad {
                    sortedHours.insert(nil, at: i)
                }
            }
```

Comment: same error - Nil is not compatible with expected argument type

Comment: @Siva Show me how you use it because it works for me

Comment: The logic also changed after changing into optional

Comment: @Siva if you want to pass in nil, it needs to be optional. This is how Swift works, non optional fields can only be of the type defined. Optional means it can be of type `GymHours` or `nil`

Comment: @Siva exactly the same comment  Simon McLoughlin